# iOS to Cloud Function and Back

Tags: node.js, swift, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to integrate my iOS Swift App with Cloud Functions using onCall. However, my simple service refuses to send data back.

Here is my function:

```
exports.getText = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    var public_token = data.public_token;


    if (!(typeof public_token === 'string') || public_token.length === 0) {
        // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with ' +
            'one arguments "text" containing the message text to add.');
    }


    const docRef = admin.firestore().doc(`/PlaidUsers/` + public_token);

    docRef.get().then(function(doc) {

        if (doc.exists) {
            return {"text" : "test"};

        } else {
            return {"text" : "Document doesn't exist"};
        }

    }).catch(error => {
        return {"text" : "Error getting document"};

    });

});
```

It does deploy successfully to the Cloud Functions

Here is my simple Swift code:

```
 self.functions.httpsCallable("getText").call(["public_token" : self.userMap["plaidPublicToken"]]) { (result, error) in
                    if let error = error as NSError? {
                        if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                            let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
                            let message = error.localizedDescription
                            let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
                            print(message)
                        }
                        // ...
                    }
                    if let text = (result?.data as? [String: Any])?["text"] as? String {
                        print (text)
                    }
                }
```

I do not get errors just a null result.

Comment: FYI you can format an entire code section by selecting the entire snippet and using the {} button in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, `then` and `catch` are asynchronous callback methods.  You can't return data out of them to be returned by a containing function.  Your function is indeed return nothing back to the client, because there is no return statement at the top level of the function.

`then` and `catch` both return another promise that resolves with the value returned by their callback methods.  So try putting a return at the top level of the promise chain:

```
return docRef.get().then(...).catch(...)
```

Comment: Indeed I missed the return. Thank you and your explanation was great.